# Script to Create IIS Site Failing

Tags: iis, powershell

I am trying to use the new `IISAdministration` module to create an IIS site (I know I can use the old `WebAdministration` module, but this is now the recommended approach).

When I run the following script, I get the error that follows it:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration

New-IISSite -Name "IdpSAMLBridge" -BindingInformation "*:7777:demo.something.com" -PhysicalPath "C:\inetpub\IdpSAMLBridge\abc5" -Protocol https -CertificateThumbPrint "284c9018f6f6258a05c48ab9e34f6fe2133cff1b" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

And the error:

```
New-IISSite : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Protocol'.

 ... indingInformation '*:12031:ictctst.incontrol.local' -Protocol https - ...
                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-IISSite], ParameterBindingException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.IIS.Powershell.Commands.NewIISSiteCommand
```

My code seems to be correct, if this doco is still correct and current.

If I swap around the parameters, I get a similar error, but a different parameter:

```
New-IISSite : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CertificateThumbPrint'.
At C:\Users\David\Documents\scripts\create-idp.ps1:3 char:132
+ ... tion '*:12031:ictctst.incontrol.local' -CertificateThumbPrint 'f62d70 ...
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-IISSite], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.IIS.Powershell.Commands.NewIISSiteCommand
```

However, if I remove some of the parameters, the command works:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration

New-IISSite -Name "IdpSAMLBridge" -PhysicalPath 'C:\inetpub\IdpSAMLBridge\abc5' -BindingInformation '*:12033:demo.something.com'
```

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Thanks

Comment: Does the directory C:\inetpub\IdpSAMLBridge\abc5 exist? Can you show what's in there?

Comment: The directory does exist. Its got a deployed ASP.NET application. There are several such sites on this server. I created those ones in IIS manually.

Comment: Try using New-WebSite, I never had any problems with that one. Hardly ever use the *-IIS* ones.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf But that's my whole goal. To do it using the new Module. I know the WebAdministration module stuff works. But I want to learn how to do it using `IISAdministration`. And I can't, for the life of me, understand why it is not working.

Comment: Oh hey, you've completely swapped around which error message you're getting.

Comment: @Grilse yeah. That's on me. I edited the question with more details. This was the error I was getting on the server. I thought it was the same on my laptop, until I looked a lot closer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely attempting to use the OS-native version of the module which is 1.0.0.0 and not as feature rich as the current version 1.1.0.0 which is available via [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/IISAdministration/) and is also bundled with Windows Server 2022.

You can verify your version with the following command:

```perl
Get-Module -List IISAdministration
```

You can also verify the available parameters like this:

```perl
Get-Help New-IISSite
```

Here's a blog post from the IIS team announcing the new version of the module back in 2017.
https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iisadministration-in-the-powershell-gallery

Comment: Yup, that's the badger: "We’ve also updated the New-IISSite cmdlet to allow you specify a HTTPS binding at site creation."

Comment: @Ryan Bolger Awesome! whilst I read the docs, I did not know about that blog post. Thanks for sharing your knowlege. My Google-fu did not even pick it up.